# How to tweak the NLTK sentence tokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm using NLTK to analyze a few classic texts and I'm running in to trouble tokenizing the text by sentence. For example, here's what I get for a snippet from *[Moby Dick](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2701/pg2701.txt)*:

```
import nltk
sent_tokenize = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

'''
(Chapter 16)
A clam for supper? a cold clam; is THAT what you mean, Mrs. Hussey?" says I, "but
that's a rather cold and clammy reception in the winter time, ain't it, Mrs. Hussey?"
'''
sample = 'A clam for supper? a cold clam; is THAT what you mean, Mrs. Hussey?" says I, "but that\'s a rather cold and clammy reception in the winter time, ain\'t it, Mrs. Hussey?"'

print "\n-----\n".join(sent_tokenize.tokenize(sample))
'''
OUTPUT
"A clam for supper?
-----
a cold clam; is THAT what you mean, Mrs.
-----
Hussey?
-----
" says I, "but that\'s a rather cold and clammy reception in the winter time, ain\'t it, Mrs.
-----
Hussey?
-----
"
'''
```

I don't expect perfection here, considering that Melville's syntax is a bit dated, but NLTK ought to be able to handle terminal double quotes and titles like "Mrs." Since the tokenizer is the result of an unsupervised training algo, however, I can't figure out how to tinker with it.

Anyone have recommendations for a better sentence tokenizer? I'd prefer a simple heuristic that I can hack rather than having to train my own parser.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to supply a list of abbreviations to the tokenizer, like so:

```
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer, PunktParameters
punkt_param = PunktParameters()
punkt_param.abbrev_types = set(['dr', 'vs', 'mr', 'mrs', 'prof', 'inc'])
sentence_splitter = PunktSentenceTokenizer(punkt_param)
text = "is THAT what you mean, Mrs. Hussey?"
sentences = sentence_splitter.tokenize(text)
```

sentences is now:

```
['is THAT what you mean, Mrs. Hussey?']
```

Update: This does not work if the last word of the sentence has an apostrophe or a quotation mark attached to it (like **Hussey?'**). So a quick-and-dirty way around this is to put spaces in front of apostrophes and quotes that follow sentence-end symbols (.!?):

```
text = text.replace('?"', '? "').replace('!"', '! "').replace('."', '. "')
```

Comment: Ah, good to know. Strangely, this does not work if I run the complete sentence in my question through your solution. Any idea why?

Comment: Just added some more info into the answer.

Comment: I generally avoid 'thanks' comments, but here it really is at place: thanks!

Comment: How do you handle the special case where the sentence has an apostrophe but you want to get the offsets?
i.e. using ``span_tokenize`` method .
The suggested workaround changes the original offsets.

Comment: The problem with this answer is it doesn't "tweak" the existing English tokenizer. You're going to lose a lot of the other features you might want if you create one from scratch. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25375857/4582054

Answer (score 41):

You can modify the NLTK's pre-trained English sentence tokenizer to recognize more abbreviations by adding them to the set `_params.abbrev_types`. For example:

```
extra_abbreviations = ['dr', 'vs', 'mr', 'mrs', 'prof', 'inc', 'i.e']
sentence_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
sentence_tokenizer._params.abbrev_types.update(extra_abbreviations)
```

Note that the abbreviations must be specified without the final period, but do include any internal periods, as in `'i.e'` above. For details about the other tokenizer parameters, refer to [the relevant documentation.](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktParameters)

Comment: This should be the top answer. If you just create a new tokenizer you won't get all the existing features of the English tokenizer.

Comment: It didn't seem to work for me, whereas the top answer did.

Comment: @Alter You have to use it like so: `sentence_tokenizer.tokenize(text)`

Comment: This also works for pickled customized tokenizers where you don't have to re-train it. (for languages that Punkt does not support)

Comment: Be aware that `nltk.data.load()` uses a [cache by default](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.data.html?highlight=nltk%20data%20load#nltk.data.load). So modifying `sentence_tokenizer._params` will also affect methods like `nltk.sent_tokenize()`. You can pass `cache=False` to avoid this.

Answer (score 10):

You can tell the `PunktSentenceTokenizer.tokenize` method to include "terminal" double quotes with the rest of the sentence by setting the `realign_boundaries` parameter to `True`. See the code below for an example.

I do not know a clean way to prevent text like `Mrs. Hussey` from being split into two sentences. However, here is a hack which

- mangles all occurrences of `Mrs. Hussey` to `Mrs._Hussey`,
- then splits the text into sentences with `sent_tokenize.tokenize`,
- then for each sentence, unmangles `Mrs._Hussey` back to `Mrs. Hussey`

I wish I knew a better way, but this might work in a pinch.

---

```
import nltk
import re
import functools

mangle = functools.partial(re.sub, r'([MD]rs?[.]) ([A-Z])', r'\1_\2')
unmangle = functools.partial(re.sub, r'([MD]rs?[.])_([A-Z])', r'\1 \2')

sent_tokenize = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

sample = '''"A clam for supper? a cold clam; is THAT what you mean, Mrs. Hussey?" says I, "but that\'s a rather cold and clammy reception in the winter time, ain\'t it, Mrs. Hussey?"'''    

sample = mangle(sample)
sentences = [unmangle(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize.tokenize(
    sample, realign_boundaries = True)]    

print u"\n-----\n".join(sentences)
```

yields

```
"A clam for supper?
-----
a cold clam; is THAT what you mean, Mrs. Hussey?"
-----
says I, "but that's a rather cold and clammy reception in the winter time, ain't it, Mrs. Hussey?"
```

Comment: Update: Consolidated part of this answer with the one above

Answer (score 3):

So I had a similar issue and tried out vpekar's solution above.

Perhaps mine is some sort of edge case but I observed the same behavior after applying the replacements, however, when I tried replacing the punctuation with the quotations placed before them, I got the output I was looking for. Presumably lack of adherence to MLA is less important than retaining the original quote as a single sentence.

To be more clear:

```
text = text.replace('?"', '"?').replace('!"', '"!').replace('."', '".')
```

If MLA is important though you could always go back and reverse these changes wherever it counts.