# Why does NLTK mis-tokenize quote at end of sentence?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

Given a string:

```
c = 'A problem. She said: "I don\'t know about it."'
```

And an attempt to tokenize it:

```
>>> for sindex,sentence in enumerate(sent_tokenize(c)):
...     print str(sindex)+": "+sentence
...
0: A problem.
1: She said: "I don't know about it.
2: "
>>>
```

Why does NLTK put the end quote of sentence 2 into its own sentence 3? Is there a way to correct this behavior?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the default `sent_tokenize`, what you'll need is the realignment feature that is already pre-coded pre-trained in the `punkt` sentence tokenizer.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> st2 = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
>>> sent = 'A problem. She said: "I don\'t know about it."'
>>> st2.tokenize(sent, realign_boundaries=True)
['A problem.', 'She said: "I don\'t know about it."']
```

see `6   Punkt Tokenizer` section from http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/tokenize.html

Comment: you will run into fullstop tokenization problems for examples `mr. john` but there's a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095971/how-to-tweak-the-nltk-sentence-tokenizer

Answer (score 1):

The default sentence tokenizer is `PunktSentenceTokenizer` that detects a new sentence each time it founds a period except, for example, the period belongs to an acronym like U.S.A.

In nltk documentation there are examples of how to train a new sentence splitter with different corpus. You can find it [here.](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html#sec-further-examples-of-supervised-classification)

So I guess that your problem can't be solved with the default sentence tokenizer and you have to train a new one and try.