# 'PunktSentenceTokenizer' object is not callable

Tags: python, nltk

I am new to pyhton and nltk.I want to tokenize a string and add a few string to the split list in nltk.I used the code from the post [How to tweak the NLTK sentence tokenizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095971/how-to-tweak-the-nltk-sentence-tokenizer). Below is the code which I have written

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
extra_abbreviations = ['\n']
sentence_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
sentence_tokenizer._params.abbrev_types.update(extra_abbreviations)

sent_tokenize_list = sentence_tokenizer(document)
sent_tokenize_list
```

### This gives me the following error:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      4 sentence_tokenizer._params.abbrev_types.update(extra_abbreviations)
      5 
----> 6 sent_tokenize_list = sentence_tokenizer(document)
      7 sent_tokenize_list

TypeError: 'PunktSentenceTokenizer' object is not callable

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hopefully, this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35279885/610569 and https://github.com/alvations/DLTK/blob/master/dltk/tokenize/tokenizer.py#L49

Answer (score 3):

This makes your example work:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
extra_abbreviations = ['\n']
sentence_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
sentence_tokenizer._params.abbrev_types.update(extra_abbreviations)
document = """This is my test doc. It has two sentences; however, one of wich with interesting punctuation."""
sent_tokenize_list = sentence_tokenizer.tokenize(document)
print(sent_tokenize_list)
```

Your error is due to the fact that `sentence_tokenizer` is an object. You have to call the function `tokenize` on the object.

Learn how to find out more about the capabilities of objects [in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/inspect.html)