# How to sentence tokenize based on semi colon using nltk

Tags: nltk

Hi everbody I am new to text processing, so any help is appreciated. I am trying to sentence tokenize based on period AND semi colons. How can I do this using `nltk.sent_tokenize`?

For example if we have this sentence and we sentence tokenize it:

```
sentence = "The court ruled out the judgement; First round proceedings; The court declared unjustfied. Case proceedings were carried out in the morning. Objections were raised;"

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(sentence)
```

`sentences` should be:

```
[
 "The court ruled out the judgement;",
 "First round proceedings;",
 "The court declared unjustfied.",
 "Case proceedings were carried out in the morning.",
 "Objections were raised;"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been addressed in a [previous post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095971/how-to-tweak-the-nltk-sentence-tokenizer). You can do so by updating `sent_end_chars` in the default tokenizer in nltk (`PunktTokenizer`) using `PunktLangVars` as below:

```py
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer, PunktLanguageVars

# Create new lang vars with semicolon
class MyLangVars(PunktLanguageVars):
    sent_end_chars = {'.', '?', '!', ';'}

# Create tokenizer with new language variables
tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(lang_vars = MyLangVars())

# Tokenize text
sentence = "The court ruled out the judgement; First round proceedings; The court declared unjustfied. Case proceedings were carried out in the morning. Objections were raised;"
sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
print(sentences)
```

This has output:

```
[
'The court ruled out the judgement;', 
'First round proceedings;', 
'The court declared unjustfied.', 
'Case proceedings were carried out in the morning.', 
'Objections were raised;'
]
```